# Prevent Webview to open browser without using WebViewClient

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I need to load url in WebView and DO NOT open default browser of device, without setting WebViewClient/WebChromeClient.
The reason i need to prevent using WebViewClient while loading url in webview is that, without WebViewClient urls loading 2,3 times faster.

Problem is that i have multiple urls and some of urls opening default browser of device.